# WC displaying products from category

Tags: wp-query, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm currently working on shop page and custom product loop. With **WP_Query** I can succesfully display products based on meta_key and meta_val but i run into trouble.
Now i have to display all products from category and as argument i need to pass category_id. This is my code:

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' =>12,
    //   get category by slug is working -
            'product_cat' =>  'products-from-cat-40',
          );
```

I know that woocommerce have slightly different query arguments than wordpress so i've tried so far:

- product_cat_id
- product_cat
- product_category
- product_category_id
- cat
- cat_id
- category_id

As ID i passed both integer and string but still nothing works. I've searched trough internet for list of viable Woocommerce WP_Query arguments and i couldn't find it. Can anyone help? I'll much appreciate.

Comment: And does the category with slug 'products-from-cat-40' really exist?

Comment: That was only example. The problem is solved so i guess you want to use this code in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom taxonomies, including Product Categories, you should use the [`tax_query` argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'terms'    => 40,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Comment: You should also avoid using `WP_Query()` to retrieve WooCommerce products. See more info here: https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/